# Why does flutter firestore plugin not worry about closing its sinks (snapshot streams)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In the flutter firestore codebase you can find [a comment about](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/403b5bb728562479bf3f2793a0aad5e257be57f7/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart#L127-L129) the stream it creates when you run snapshots() on a query.

```
// It's fine to let the StreamController be garbage collected once all the
// subscribers have cancelled; this analyzer warning is safe to ignore.
StreamController<QuerySnapshotPlatform> controller; // ignore: close_sinks
```

I want to wrap my resulting snapshot streams with a BehaviorSubject so I can keep track of the latest entry. This is useful when I have one stream that is at the top of a page that I want to be consumed through different widgets farther down in my tree without reloading the stream each time. Without keeping track in a BehaviorSubject or elsewhere if a new widget starts listening to that stream it does not get the most recent information from Firestore as it missed that event.

Can I also not worry about closing the behavior subject I am going to create as it will be garbage collected when there are no more listeners? Or is there another way to achieve what I am wanting?

I'm picturing code like this:

```
final snapshotStream = _firestore.collection('users').snapshots();
final behaviorSubjectStream = BehaviorSubject();
behaviorSubjectStream.addStream(snapshotStream);
return behaviorSubjectStream;
```

This will get a complaint that I don't close the behaviorSubjectStream. Is it ok to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you listen to the subject.

From what you describe, it sounds safe to ignore the hint. When the subscriptions that listen to the subject are cancelled, the subject will be cancelled as well (when the garbage collector finds it).

There are situations where you have a subscription that is still listening, but you want the subject to stop emitting. In that case you will need to `close()` the subject.

You can test that the subject is correctly cancelled by adding

```dart
behaviorSubjectStream.onCancel = () {
    print("onCancel");
};
```

Then you can test it by playing around with your app.